# error with the memory in duplicate

Tags: c

Hello i have this code and when it reaches the second printf there is an error compiler...i think it's about the pointer *y of the function

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    int *x,*y;
    void duplicate(int*x,int *y,int elem){
    int j;
    y=(int*)malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
     for(j=0;j<elem;j++){
       y[j]=x[j];
       x[j]=x[j]+1;
     }
   }
    int main(){
    int j;
    y=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   *y=10;*(y+1)=50;
    duplicate(y,x,2);
     printf("the poin y con y[0]=%d and y[1]=%d\n",y[0],y[1]);
     printf("the poin y con x[0]=%d and x[1]=%d\n",x[0],x[1]);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What error? Please [edit] your post and add it.

Comment: x is not initialize or assigned

Comment: what is x in main.Its not initialised

Comment: You don't need to cast `void *` in c, are you using a c++ compiler?

Comment: You have written a very simple program in the most confusing way possible :)

Comment: Before doing anything else, get rid of the global variables, and use different names than `x` and `y` corresponding to `y` and `x` !  You are just confusing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory for `y` (which is the global `x`) in function `duplicate()`, it doesn't update the global `x` because `y` is a local variable in `duplicate()`.

You don't need to pass `x` from `main()` as it's a global variable. If you *do* need to pass then pass a pointer to pointer to update it:

```
duplicate(y,&x,2);
```

and update the function `duplicate()` to use `*y`:

```
*y=malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
```

and so on.

**Suggestions:**

1. Casting the return value of `malloc` is [dangerous](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html) in C.
2. Don't write variable names as confusing as you did here. `x` is a global variable but you are passing it to a function but calling `y` there.
3. Use a standard signature for main() such as: `int main(void)`.

Comment: you mean to do this?                                                                                                     #include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int *x,*y;
void duplicate(int*x,int **y,int elem){
 int j;
 *y=(int*)malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
 for(j=0;j<elem;j++){
  *(y[j])=x[j];
  x[j]=x[j]+1;
 }
}
int main(){
 int j;
 y=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
 *y=10;*(y+1)=50;
 duplicate(y,&x,2);
 printf("the poin y con y[0]=%d and y[1]=%d\n",y[0],y[1]);
 printf("the poin y con x[0]=%d and x[1]=%d\n",x[0],x[1]);
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you change the memory address of the pointer `y` within the `duplicate`.

When you pass a pointer to a function, a copy of that pointer is created as a local variable in the function. It still points at the same `int`, so if you dereference the pointer and change the value of the integer, that new value is retained when you return from the function. However, if you change the memory address that is pointed to, as with `malloc`, only the *local copy* of the pointer is changed, and the global variable `y` still points to some unallocated address which may contain garbage or cause a segmentation fault.

To fix this, you could pass a pointer to a pointer - i.e. `int** y`, or alternatively you could have duplicate return the new memory address:

```
int * duplicate(int*x,int *y,int elem){
int j;
y=(int*)malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
 for(j=0;j<elem;j++){
   y[j]=x[j];
   x[j]=x[j]+1;
 }
return y;
}
```

Then in `main()` call it as:

```
x = duplicate(y,x,2);
```

Of course, there is no actual reason to pass the target pointer to the `duplicate` function, so you can simplify it to this:

```
int * duplicate(int*x,int elem){
int j;
int *y;
y=(int*)malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
 for(j=0;j<elem;j++){
   y[j]=x[j];
   /* I'm not sure why you have this line here, bug? */
   x[j]=x[j]+1;
 }
return y;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
x = duplicate(y,2);
```

Comment: the fact that the x and y as glabal variables have the same name with the x and y einai my function but with a different way is because our teacher asked as to do this for practise...i just want to change only the duplicate and it's call nothing else

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int *x,*y;
void duplicate(int*x,int **y,int elem){
 int j;
 *y=(int*)malloc(elem*sizeof(int));
 for(j=0;j<elem;j++){
  *(y[j])=x[j];
  x[j]=x[j]+1;
 }
}
int main(){
 int j;
 y=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
 *y=10;*(y+1)=50;
 duplicate(y,&x,2);
 printf("the poin y con y[0]=%d and y[1]=%d\n",y[0],y[1]);
 printf("the poin y con x[0]=%d and x[1]=%d\n",x[0],x[1]);
 return 0;
}